# Ubuntu 14.04: crontab -e open a weird file

Tags: server, cron, ubuntu-14.04

Since I've reboot my server now when I open my crontab file using

> crontab -e

Vim is opening a file called:

> /tmp/crontab.yWhf4u/crontab

Who is empty...

I would like to know what I did wrong and how I can fix my mistake, please?

My command to reboot the server was

> shutdown -r now

Answer (score 0):

`crontab -e` creates a temporary file that's a copy of your crontab. After you leave the editor, it rereads the temporary file and uses it to update your crontab. (Your actual crontab is in a file in a system directory that you won't have access to without root permissions. Don't try to edit that file directly.)

Apparently your crontab is empty. `crontab -l` dumps the contents of your crontab to standard output; if that produces no output, it will verify that you have an empty crontab.

You didn't say so, but I presume you thought you had a non-empty crontab. It's easy to clobber your crontab accidentally. For example, if you type `crontab` with no arguments, it will read a new crontab from standard input; if you then type ctrl-D, it will replace your existing crontab with an empty one.

There's not really a good way to restore your previous crontab. It might exist in a system backup.

In the future, I suggest keeping a copy of your crontab in a separate file, backed up in some way (I use a version control system), and use `crontab filename` to load the contents of that file into your crontab. That way if you accidentally clobber your crontab, you can easily reload it.